# How many such strings are there?

Tags: combinatorics

How many 50($=n$) digit strings($=f(n)$) composed of only zeros and ones are there such that all "ones" should be in groups of at least 3(The grouping should be explicit), if they occur and must be separated by atleast one "zero".

Valid Examples:
$$(111)0(111),\;\;\;(1111)00(111)0(11111)0(111)000$$
InValid Examples:
$$(111)(11),\;\;(111)(111),\;\;(111)0(11)$$

It is easy to find it by explicitly writing for lower n. Also it seems that $f(n)$ follows recursion but I can't write it.

I also tried using stars and bars with no progress.

An Explanatory Example:
$$f(7)=17$$
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline 1&0000000&10&00(1111)0\\2&(111)0000&11&000(1111)\\3&0(111)000&12&0(1111)00\\4&00(111)00&13&00(1111)0\\5&000(111)0&14&000(1111)\\6&0000(111)&15&(11111)00\\7&(111)0(111)&16&0(11111)0\\8&(1111)000&17&1111111\\9&0(1111)00&&\\\hline\end{array}$$

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "must be seperated by at least 1 zeros"? is "1111" a valid string?

Comment: So can you give a string that satisfies the first but not the second condition?

Comment: @Tintarn see edit.

Comment: @Tintarn No you should show the grouping explicitly, see the edit. Infact I told you wrongly the first time.

Comment: Just to make sure that I now understand it right: If you want the grouping to be explicit you need to count (111)(1111) and (1111)(111) as two different strings, right?

Comment: @Tintarn yes indeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's a more elementary way to find a recursion:

Denote $a(n)$ be the number of such strings that end up with a 0.

Denote $b(n)$ the number of strings that end up with a 1.

Now, we find $f(n)=a(n)+b(n)$.

Also, easily we obtain $a(n+1)=f(n)=a(n)+b(n)$ since we can add a 0 to any string.

Now, we are left to find a recursion for $b(n+1)$.

For any such string, the last three digits need to be "ones". So if at the end we have exactly $k$ "ones" (here $k \ge 3$) we have $a(n+1-k)$ ways to choose the remaining string.

So $b(n+1)=a(n-2)+a(n-3)+\dotsc+a(1)+1$ i.e. $b(n+1)=b(n)+a(n-2)$.

Now, we are able to solve for $f(n)$.

Using our first recursion, we find $b(n)=a(n+1)-a(n)$.

Plugging this into the second recursion, we find
$$a(n+2)=2a(n+1)-a(n)+a(n-2)$$
Since we established $a(n)=f(n-1)$ above, we further conclude
$$f(n+2)=2f(n+1)-f(n)+f(n-2)$$
This together with the starting values $f(0)=f(1)=f(2)=1, f(3)=2$ gives the correct values
$f(4)=4, f(5)=7, f(6)=11, f(7)=17$ so it seems to work...

Of course, solving the characteristic equation $x^4-2x^3+x^2-1=0$ we can find a closed formula for $f(n)$ but this does not give much more insight than the recursion.

Comment: very nice... thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Let $f_0(n),f_1(n),f_2(n),f_{\ge3}(n)$ be the number of such strings ending in $0,1,2,,\ge3$ ones. Then we have recursions
$$\begin{align} f_0(n+1)&=f_0(n)+f_{\ge3}(n)\\
f_1(n+1)&=f_0(n)\\
f_2(n+1)&=f_1(n)\\
f_{\ge3}(n+1)&=f_2(n)+f_{\ge3}(n)
\end{align}$$
or in matrix form: We multiply $(f_0(n),f_1(n)f_2(n),f_{\ge3}(n))^T$ by
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&1\\1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&1\end{pmatrix} $$
and find from this that
$$f(n)=f_0(n)+f_{\ge3}(n)=\alpha_1\lambda_1^n+\alpha_2\lambda_2^n+\alpha_3\lambda_3^n+\alpha_4\lambda_4^n $$
where the $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues of $A$ and the $\alpha_i$ can be obtained from $f(0),f(1),f(2),f(3)$.

It turns out that the eignevalues are $\frac{1\pm\sqrt 5}{2}$ and $\frac{1\pm i\sqrt 3}2$ and using $f(0)=f(1)=f(2)=1$, $f(3)=2$ we arrive after a bit of playing around at
$$ f(n)=\underbrace{\frac1{2\sqrt 5}\left(\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}\right)^{n+2}-\frac1{2\sqrt 5}\left(\frac{1-\sqrt 5}{2}\right)^{n+2}}_{=\frac12F_{n+2}}+\frac1{\sqrt 3}\sin\frac{(n+2)\pi}{3}$$
For example
$$f(7)=\frac12 F_9+\frac1{\sqrt 3}\sin3\pi=17. $$

Comment: This solution does not take into account the latest edit of the problem statement (regarding the grouping of digits).

Comment: @Tintarn I bet it does

Comment: But where do you encounter that after adding 1 to 111111 (which has two possible groupings: (111111) and (111)(111)) you obtain 1111111 which has three possible groupings: (1111111), (111)(1111) and (1111)(111)?

Comment: @Tintarn most o fthese groupings are not allowed as they lack the separating zeroes

Comment: I added a very clear example of f(7)=17

Comment: I now see my mistake. Sorry for the confusion..